# Javascript click event not running on all class elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button of class 'add' which, when clicked simply clones itself and its other div siblings.  The cloning works fine, however the click functionality only works on the first instance of the button (the one that loads with the page) and not on any subsequent instances.

Any help would be great.

```
$('.add').click(function(){
        cloneDiv();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the `live` method for *dynamically added elements*:](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('.add').live('click', function(){
    // your code...
});
```

Comment: Super fast and spot on.  At the risk of looking like eBay feedback... AAA++++++